# How to sort and visualize a directed graph?

Tags: r, graph-theory, data-visualization, igraph

I am using R with [igraph](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html) and I have a square matrix with weights. I want to sort it. I thought to use `page.rank(g)` and I got a corresponding vector and its values.

```
library(igraph)
g<-get.matrix()
page.rank(g)$value
page.rank(g)$vector
```

Now I want to sort using this values and visualizing it in a graph if it is possible.
Something similar to the following picture:

[image]

How I could do this?

Comment: A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/420055) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a force-based layout and set the vertex size (`vertex.size`) to be proportional to the page rank values. See an example [on the igraph homepage](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/screenshots2.html#2) on how to set the vertex size. (The example  uses `tkplot`, but you can just use `plot` instead of that.) You can set the vertex labels via the `vertex.label` argument to `plot`, and `\n` is allowed to make multi-line labels.